# Please assist in the creation of a pure css slide in panel on click instead of hover

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FUAQJ/714/) example.  I need this to not be on hover but on click.  I've read about the checkbox hack but when I try to apply it to this fiddle it breaks it.

I tried to add a checkbox to the page and then check if it was checked with

`#checky:checked`

instead of the :hover bit.

Here i tried on hover:

```css
#slideout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #6DAD53;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: -250px;
    background: #6DAD53;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 130px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner textarea {
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#slideout:hover {
    left: 250px;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="http://img.usabilitypost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/css_slideout/feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post feedback"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone out there explain how the checkbox hack works and apply it to this example?

Comment: Can you use jquery ?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in **the question itself**.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want yo use `Jquery` you can try like this -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideout img').click(function(){
        $('#slideout').animate({
        'left' : $('#slideout').css('left') == '0px' ? '250px' : '0px'
        }, 200);
        $('#slideout_inner').animate({
        'left' : $('#slideout_inner').css('left') == '-250px' ? '0px' : '-250px'
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

```css
#slideout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #6DAD53;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#slideout img{
  cursor:pointer
}

#slideout_inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: -250px;
    background: #6DAD53;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 130px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner textarea {
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="http://img.usabilitypost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/css_slideout/feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post feedback"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use javascript or jquery for this..here is a javascript solution (Note...Clicking on the **feedback image** will cause the toggle)

```js
function toggle(e){
 if(this.parentNode.style.left!='250px'){

    this.parentNode.style.left='250px'
 this.nextElementSibling.style.left='0px';
 }
  else{
    this.parentNode.style.left='0px'
    this.nextElementSibling.style.left='-250px';
  }
}
document.querySelector('#slideout img').addEventListener('click',toggle,false)
```

```css
#slideout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #6DAD53;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: -250px;
    background: #6DAD53;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 130px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner textarea {
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
/*#slideout:hover {
    left: 250px;
} */
/*#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
    left: 0;
}*/
```

```html
<div id="slideout">
    <img src="http://img.usabilitypost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/css_slideout/feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post feedback"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your example, If click on textarea, the panel is closed .

Comment: Thank you..sharp eye....

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do with only css following way.

Use checkbox for that. And When checkbox checked slideout the div.

```css
.main{
  position:fixed;
  top:40px;
  left:0;
}
#slideout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 35px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #6DAD53;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: -250px;
    background: #6DAD53;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 130px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#slideout_inner textarea {
    width: 190px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#feedbackswitch:checked ~ #feedbackimg #slideout {
    left: 250px;
}

#feedbackswitch:checked ~ #feedbackimg #slideout_inner {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<input type="checkbox" name="feedbackswitch" class="feedback-checkbox" id="feedbackswitch"  />
<label for="feedbackswitch" id="feedbackimg">
<div id="slideout">
    
    <img for="feedbackswitch" src="http://img.usabilitypost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/css_slideout/feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
    
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post feedback" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Bubbling on the slideout_inner seems be the cause of the div closing whenever it gets clicked on.  Is there any way to stop it doing this?